# Are there any advantages to testing unauthorized-by-cancan actions at the controller level, or is this superfluous?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cancan

Say I have the following CanCan abilities defined

```
can :index, Project
cannot :show, Project
```

and an ability_spec

```
it { is_expected.to have_abilities([:index], Project }
it { is_expected.to not_have_abilities([:show], Project }
```

are there any situations where it is advantageous to test the unauthorized action at the controller level, or is this superfluous?

```
describe "GET #show" do
  it "raises Access Denied" do 
    expect { 
      get :show, { id: subject.id} 
    }.to raise_error(CanCan::AccessDenied)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that just having your ability configuration specs is fine since that exercises your app's business logic.  The functionality of raising a `CanCan::AccessDenied` error when an ability is unauthorised to perform an action is [specced in the CanCan library itself](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/4560928dc375f9b31de00381c98334eb6aabc4b9/spec/cancan/ability_spec.rb#L341).

If you had your own custom error classes that you were using when access is denied, then I think the case could probably be made to write the kind of controller specs you've mentioned.

Comment: thanks for confirming this @paul. Will help streamlining a bloated controller test suite!